# Give a predetermined number as the amount of experience

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm creating a *datapack* to give players experience for doing all kinds of stuff. As I am expanding, I've come to a point where it would be easier to keep track of the scores by having all the different amounts of experience stored in a single place. But I give the experience using a loop, as follows:

```
execute as @a  
run execute if score @s Cutting_Count = @s Cutting_XP 
run experience add @s 1
```

Is there a way to give a predetermined amount?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research, I think there's no way of doing that directly. A solution would be making a function to check if a given score matches an interger.

First create a *dummy scoreboard*:

```
scoreboard objectives add XP_Amount dummy
```

Then set a *value* and make it clear that it has limitations:

```
# Min = 1 | Max = 10
execute as @a run scoreboard players set @s XP_Amount 1
```

Then run a *function* to check if it *matches* the given value:

```
execute as @a run function skelun/give_xp
```

The *function* would look like this:

```
execute if score @s XP_Amount matches 1 run experience add @s 1
execute if score @s XP_Amount matches 2 run experience add @s 2
execute if score @s XP_Amount matches 3 run experience add @s 3
execute if score @s XP_Amount matches 4 run experience add @s 4
execute if score @s XP_Amount matches 5 run experience add @s 5
execute if score @s XP_Amount matches 6 run experience add @s 6
execute if score @s XP_Amount matches 7 run experience add @s 7
execute if score @s XP_Amount matches 8 run experience add @s 8
execute if score @s XP_Amount matches 9 run experience add @s 9
execute if score @s XP_Amount matches 10 run experience add @s 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using functions, you can do a recursive function, so that you dont need to do a line for each amount needed to be added.

You give a single Xp level, subtract from the Xp_amount, and if the xp_amount is bigger than 0, call it again. You can also add one for 5, 10, 20... just to make the process faster.

```
execute if score @s XP_Amount matches 20.. run experience add @s 20
execute if score @s XP_Amount matches 20.. run scoreboard players remove @s XP_Amount 20

execute if score @s XP_Amount matches 10.. run experience add @s 10
execute if score @s XP_Amount matches 10.. run scoreboard players remove @s XP_Amount 10

execute if score @s XP_Amount matches 5.. run experience add @s 5
execute if score @s XP_Amount matches 5.. run scoreboard players remove @s XP_Amount 5

execute if score @s XP_Amount matches 1.. run experience add @s 1
execute if score @s XP_Amount matches 1.. run scoreboard players remove @s XP_Amount 1

execute if score @s XP_Amount matches 1.. run function skelun/give_xp
```

In theory, all you need is:

```
execute if score @s XP_Amount matches 1.. run experience add @s 1
execute if score @s XP_Amount matches 1.. run scoreboard players remove @s XP_Amount 1

execute if score @s XP_Amount matches 1.. run function skelun/give_xp
```